# How I can hide bulk products or Price in WooCommerce?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, woocommerce

I am using WooCommerce in WordPress. I have a lot of products with different prices. I just want to hide products which have $35 price bracket. I don't want to do it one by one using editor. I want a solution with code because 5000+ products have $35 price.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with the `woocommerce_product_is_visible` hook

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_is_visible', 'hide_35', 10, 2 );
 
function hide_35( $visible, $id ){
    $product = wc_get_product( $id );
    if( $product->get_regular_price() == 35 ){
        return false;
    }
    return $visible;
}
```